# Error thrown while trying to expand model in GXT tree grid

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am trying to expand a node(model bean) using the below command

gmisRevenueGross.setExpanded(revenueGrossBean, true);

but I get the below error

> java.lang.AssertionError: null
>       at com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.treegrid.TreeGrid.setExpanded(TreeGrid.java:673)
>       at com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.treegrid.TreeGrid.setExpanded(TreeGrid.java:644)

The same code when I put inside a handler of button,  I was able to expand the node. So I guess I am trying to expand before the dom is loaded. So is there a way to expand some nodes soon after adding it to store. For grid.setAutoExpand(true) works fine, but that expands all the node.

Comment: Which version of GXT? I believe there used to be a bug in that area, but that it was resolved to recursively expand parent nodes so that the given node could be made visible.

Comment: @ColinAlworth using version 3.1.1 and mvp4g framework, I am calling the setExpanded(parent,true) method soon after adding all the beans to the store.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, are you using GXT version 2? I think your problem was because you tried to expand the tree node before the tree grid was rendered. Check your code and make sure your tree grid was already rendered before expanding the tree node. Post your code so I can help you better.

Comment: "com.sencha.gxt" is definitely not GXT2 but at least GXT3. In GXT2 the library was called "com.extjs.gxt"

Comment: Sorry for that, but still your problem probably because you try to expand the tree when it's not rendered. What I usually do is try to use timer and set it to give some delay 1 or 2 seconds and see if it's working, if it's working then it means that you call setExpanded too fast, if it's not then it will be another problems.